# Convergence rate of quasi-newton method for non-convex objective function

Tags: algorithms, optimization, gradient-descent

Consider a real-valued $L$-smooth and **non-convex** objective function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. There exists a bound on number of iterations in order to find a (local) minima using ordinary gradient descent (see page 15-20 [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Eschmidtm/Courses/340-F19/L36b.pdf)). The basic idea is to combine the condition of $L$-smooth and gradient descent algorithm to find how many iterations are required to achieve a small gradient norm.

Is there any similar bound (or at least an order) on the number of iterations when we use quasi-newton methods (e.g. BFGS) instead of the gradient-descent? If $f$ is a convex function, there is a study of superlinear convergence rate (e.g. see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-021-01622-5#:%7E:text=As%20shown%20in%20%5B31%5D%2C,Lipschitz%20constant%20of%20the%20gradient.); I'm not certain that this reference deals with convex function, but I believe so as the convergence rate contains strong convexity parameter $\mu$). But I couldn't find any reference dealing with non-convex function $f$. It'd be great if anyone can direct me to relevant references.